# Collection view loaded in reverse order

Tags: swift, api, uicollectionview, reload

I have a collection view which is loaded based on the API(Get method).The number of entries increases when new entry is added and it is reloaded with new entry at the end.
How to reload the collection view with last showing first, second last as second and so on.

Comment: first you should try something.

Comment: @DilanAnuruddha i tried to change the flow layout from right to left,but it stayed for sometime.thats all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to display array in reverse then you can do it like this:-

```
array.reversed()
```

**OR**

if you want to display last added item on top, then insert item at first index:-

```
yourArray.append(item)
let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
collectionView.insertItems(at: [indexPath])
```

Comment: i want to show last item as first, second last item as second and so on

Comment: If you try the solution you will know the result.